# Why I can't make POST request with AngularJs

Tags: json, angularjs, jax-rs

I've got problem with AngularJS and making POST request. My json creates fine, but when I POST it on my REST service I've got problem with:

```
WARNING: No operation matching request path "/ws/resources/Users/Add" is found, Relative Path: /Add, HTTP Method: POST, ContentType: application/json, Accept: application/json,text/plain,*/*,. Please enable FINE/TRACE log level for more details.
```

I really don't know why, because my GET request works fine.

Here are samples of codes

Rest Service:

```
@Path("/Users")
@Consumes(MediaType.APPLICATION_JSON)
@Produces(MediaType.APPLICATION_JSON)
public class UserRESTResource {

    @GET
    @Path("/All")
    public List<UserDto> getClients() {
        //that works fine
    }

    @POST
    @Path("/Add/{user}")
    public void add(@PathParam("user") UserDto userDto) {
        //to sth
    }
}
```

This is how I make GET request which works:

```
$http.get('resources/Users/All').success(function(data) {
        $scope.clients = data;
    });
```

This is how I make json and make POST request:

```
$scope.Add = function() {
        $http({
              method: "POST",
              url: "resources/Users/Add",
              data: {
                  "user" : {
                      "firstName" : $scope.firstNameA,
                      "lastName" : $scope.lastNameA,
                  }
              },
              headers: {'Content-Type':'application/json'}
            });
    }
```

UserDto:

```
@XmlRootElement(name = "user")
@XmlAccessorType(XmlAccessType.FIELD)
public class UserDto {
public long id;
public String firstName;
public String lastName;
}
```

What I'm doing wrong?

Answer (score 0):

I would guess that when you post, the user isn't in the URL so it won't match the route definition.

Comment: double check that the add is required with a POST method.

Comment: is this an answer or comment?

Comment: add method is annotated with @POST so user doesn't have to be in url.

Comment: This actually _does_ answer the problem, though it could be improved upon with a bit more explanation. @user3350171 remove the `/{user}` from the `@Path`, and you don't need the `@PathParam`. It's completely useless